# Getting Location of user in iOS differs with MKMapView and CLLocationManager

Tags: mkmapview, cllocationmanager

Im using CLLocationManager to get user location,In another case Im using MKMapview to show on map.

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations 
{
   16.50374457,+80.66301357 // lat and long 
}


-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

 CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];

//(latitude = 16.507553768993734, longitude = 80.664011964856343)
}
```

Two results appeared differed a little bit. As per my observation second one is most accurate. AS R & D MKMapview Uses Cllocation manager internally, But why I get differences?